# My android sdk manager only shows api 17

Tags: android

I want to download other android APIs and samples but my android SDK manager doesnt show me any other options than android sdk 4.2 API 17. Can anyone plz help me with this. Am I missing something? Thanx for your help

I tried following link,
 http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: use this download this bundle http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I download the same with win 64 bit

Comment: extract it & install it conteins Eclipse,Adt, & Latest Sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. But resolved it by checking the Proxy setup.
Tools ->Options-> Setup HTTP Proxy Server and HTTP Proxy Port. It should be the same setting as your IE Internet Connection Settings.

After the Proxy setup is complete, Go to Package -> Reload -> All previous versions of API starts to show up in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanx Jiao yu, thats exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You should update your manager first by downloading SDK Tools in your current manager.

Comment: yes i downloaded it, 
 android sdk tools - Rev 21.0.1
android sdk platform tools 16.0.1
android (4.2) 17 API
android support library

but i cant see any other options there to download, As i said i want download other APIs too with samples

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a little different than the selected answer.

In Android SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy select 'Auto-detect proxy settings'